# Qt4 - Access Windows Machine Guid from registry

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I want to access Windows Operating System's machine guid stored in windows registry. I am using Qt 4.8 on Windows 8 OS. I get an empty string only. I am following Qt's [QSettings official doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qsettings.html#platform-specific-notes)

```
   QSettings setting("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Cryptography",QSettings::NativeFormat);
    QString mGuid=setting.value("MachineGuid").toString();
    qDebug()<<"Machine Guid is: " <<mGuid;
    qDebug()<<setting.status();   // returns zero means 'no access error'
```

Output:

```
Machine Guid is:
```

I can seed `MachineGuid` in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Cryptography` in Windows registry editor. How to read guid from windows registry?

Comment: Is your application 32-bit?

Comment: @CollinDauphinee both processor and operating system are 64 bit;  don't know if application is 64 bit. How to know if my application is 32 bit or 64 bit?

Comment: @CollinDauphinee my application is 32 bit; checked in windows task manager it shows 32 bit in brackets like (32 bit).

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that Windows has a separate 64-bit and 32-bit registry view.

By default, you get the registry view that matches your application's target architecture. In this case, you're actually being redirected to the 32-bit view, so your code is checking the key located at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Cryptography`

The `MachineGuid` key, along with many other Windows-created keys, only exist in the 64-bit registry on 64-bit systems. You can specify which registry view to access from the native API, but I don't know of any way to do it through Qt.

Comment: Does any solution exists or not?

Answer (score 1):

As @Collin Dauphinee pointed out, you are probably accessing the 32-bit registry on a 64-bit windows.

If that's the case and you have access to Qt 5.7, instead of writing

```
QSettings setting("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Cryptography",QSettings::NativeFormat);
QString mGuid=setting.value("MachineGuid").toString();
```

You can write

```
QSettings setting("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Cryptography",QSettings::Registry64Format);
QString mGuid=setting.value("MachineGuid").toString();
```

That works perfectly for myself.